# Change colour scheme in TeXShop so that it matches Texmaker

Tags: texmaker, editors, texshop

I recently switched to TexShop as my editor over texmaker. My problem is that the default syntax highlighting scheme is too harsh. Is there a way to change the syntax highlighting in TeXShop so that it matches the default Texmaker color scheme?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look in the TexShop Help Panel there is a section on configuring the syntax colouring scheme.

I don't know the colour scheme of TeXMaker, but you can use the Digital Color Meter app in your Utilities folder to get values of the relevant colours if you can't look them up somewhere.

Here's the text of that panel:

> When syntax coloring is on, comments are colored red, commands are
>   colored blue, and the symbols `$`, `{`, and `}` are colored dark green.
>   These colors can be changed. A color is determined by the red, green,
>   and blue components of the color; each is a number between 0.00 and
>   1.00. To change the color of `$`, `{`, and `}` to bright green, issue the following commands in Terminal:
>
> ```
> defaults write TeXShop markerred 0.0 
> defaults write TeXShop markergreen 1.0 
> defaults write TeXShop markerblue 0.0
> ```
>
> To change the
>   comment color, replace "marker" with "comment"; to change the command
>   color, replace "marker" with "command".
>
> The background color of the source window can be changed. For example,
>   to set this background to (r, g, b) = (.42, .39, .77), issue the
>   following commands in Terminal:
>
> ```
> defaults write TeXShop background_R 0.42 
> defaults write TeXShop  background_G 0.39 
> defaults write TeXShop background_B 0.77
> ```